# How to start a job at boot time on a Plesk managed server

Tags: command, debian, plesk, boot

After upgrading to Plesk 17.8 I became surprised when I restarted the server. A  script in /etc/rc.local did not start automatically any longer. It looks as if Plesk had changed something on my server without asking or informing me. I also tried to enter a "scheduled task" on Plesk level with the cron style "@reboot", but that did not work either. So I wonder how I can start a task, that has to be executed after boot. Does anyone have a good solution for that? Plesk keeps the rc.* files in a separate place and does not allow changes to the files.

Comment: Which CentOS version are you using?

Comment: >lsb_relase -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:        8.7
Codename:       jessie

Comment: Sorry https://stackoverflow.com/users/8283497/elvis-plesky, the server is a Debian 8.7 and not an CENTOS

Answer (score 0):

After some searches I found out, how to do that in Debian for Tomcat 6:

Place an executable script into the directory /etc/init.d, which starts the job. Here is the sample code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

set -e

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
NAME=tomcat7
DESC="Tomcat servlet engine"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45

# --------------------------------------------------
# code for Debian restart
# --------------------------------------------------

echo "--- action for Tomcat ---" >>/root/restart.txt
date >>/root/restart.txt
whoami >>/root/restart.txt
echo "JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME >>/root/restart.txt

case "$1" in
  start)
    # No-op
        /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/startup.sh>>/root/restart.txt
;;
restart)
    /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/shutdown.sh>>/root/restart.txt
    /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/startup.sh>>/root/restart.txt
    ;;
  stop)
        /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.77/bin/shutdown.sh>>/root/restart.txt
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Error: $0 $1 ???" >>/root/restart.txt
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

echo "--- end Tomcat ---" >>/root/restart.txt

exit 0
```